# Code won't display "The" just keeps printing out everything

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

So, I am doing this project for my class. However I can't get the code to print out what I want. It keeps printing out the whole entire "poem".

NerdData.txt :

```
     Every man tries as hard as he can.
     The best way is this way.
     The schedule is very good.
     Cosmo Kramer is a doofus.    
     The best movie was cancelled.
```

What I got so far:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;
public class FileNerd
{
public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException
{
    Scanner sf = new Scanner(new File("C:\\temp_Timmy\\NerdData.txt"));

    int maxIndx = -1;
    String text[] = new String[1000];
    while(sf.hasNext( ))
    {
        maxIndx++;
        text[maxIndx] = sf.nextLine( ) ;
    }
    sf.close( );
    for(int j = 0; j <= maxIndx; j++)
    {
        String q = text[j];
        System.out.println(q);

        if( q.substring(3).equals("The")) {
            System.out.println(q);
        }
    }
   }
}
```

Code compiles just fine however it doesn't print out the lines that begin with the word "the" it prints out the whole entire poem.

The output I want:

```
The best way is this way.
The schedule is very good.
The best movie was cancelled.
```

Comment: ok... go over the code see the glaring problem of two system.outs

Comment: You  might consider using `String#startsWith` instead of `substring`

Comment: `public String substring(int beginIndex)`
Returns a new string that is a substring of this string. The substring begins with the character at the specified index and extends to the end of this string. [java docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring(int))

Answer (score 4):

Here you are printing every line

```
 String q = text[j];
 System.out.println(q);   // try to remove this
```

Also consider using `String.startsWith` as your substring is wrong*

```
if (q.startsWith("The")) {
    System.out.println(q);
}
```

- as per javadcos `"Harbison".substring(3) returns "bison"`

Comment: For even more efficient code consider Pattern/Matcher: `Pattern p = Pattern.compile("$The.*")` to pre-compile pattern so it isn't done every step in the loop.

Comment: @LINEMAN78 For 5 lines of text, is `Pattern` really more efficient?

Comment: No, however worth pointing out as this could be a simplified test case even though it is obviously homework. Also now that I think about it startWith may be actually be more efficient, however case sensitive. Running a test case right now...

Comment: Ran test, `Pattern` is actually slower since startsWith is actually a simple char compare, but if you wanted to do anything more complex such as case insensitive Pattern would be faster. Only noticeable over 1 million lines.

Answer (score 0):

You have one too many System.outs and your substring is wrong...

```
for(int j = 0; j <= maxIndx; j++)
{
    String q = text[j];
    System.out.println(q); // this line will print every line

    if( q.substring(3).equals("The")) { // this checks starting at char 3
        System.out.println(q);
    }
}
```

...should be...

```
for(int j = 0; j <= maxIndx; j++)
{
    String q = text[j];

    if( q.substring(0, 3).equals("The")) {
        System.out.println(q);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To test if given line starts with `The` I would use `startsWith` like

```
// Don't print every line.
// System.out.println(q); 
if (q.startsWith("The")) {
    System.out.println(q);
}
```

alternatively, to use `substring` you need `0,3` like

```
if (q.substring(0, 3).equals("The")) {
    System.out.println(q);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You print every line in your loop:

```
for(int j = 0; j <= maxIndx; j++)
{
    String q = text[j];
    System.out.println(q); // <- Here

    if( q.substring(3).equals("The")) {
        System.out.println(q);
    }
}
```

And your equality check is wrong. `"The best way is this way".substring(3)` will return `" best way is this way"`. Use [`q.startsWith("The")`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#startsWith(java.lang.String)) instead:

```
for(int j = 0; j <= maxIndx; j++)
{
    String q = text[j];
    if( q.startsWith("The")) {
        System.out.println(q);
    }
}
```